# Magento WidgetInstance is not defined / Unexpected Identifier

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, javascript, widgets, ce-1.9.2.1

Magento is throwing the following error in console when we load the CMS->Widget page there is also an error which I think is related, but what I haven't been able to solve.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
>       '`<select name="widget_instance[{{id}}][page_group]" id="widget_instance[{{id}}][page_group]" class="required-entry page_group_select select" title="" onchange="WidgetInstance.displayPageGroup(this.value+\'_{{id}}\')"><option value="" >-- Maak een keuze --</option><optgroup label="Categorieen"><option value="anchor_categories" >Verankerde Categorieen</option><option value="notanchor_categories" >Niet verankerde categorieen</option></optgroup><optgroup label="Producten"><option value="all_products" >Alle product types</option><option value="simple_products" >Simpel Product</option><option value="grouped_products" >Gegroepeerd Product</option><option value="configurable_products" >Configureerbaar Product</option><option value="virtual_products" >Virtueel product</option><option value="bundle_products" >Bundelproduct</option><option value="downloadable_products" >Download-product</option></optgroup><optgroup label="Generieke pagina\\'s"><option value="all_pages" >Alles pagina\\'s</option><option value="pages" >Specifieke pagina</option></optgroup></select>`'+

Clicking on *'add layout update'* when adding a Magento Widget (Back-end CMS->Widgets)

> Uncaught ReferenceError: WidgetInstance is not defined onclick @ (index):698

We haven't been using Widgets before, and this is an upgrade from Magento 1.7 to 1.9.2.1. I've searched the big G on it, found a single result which lead to no results. Any suggestions?

Attached screenshot for full first error:[image: Chrome Console Error log]